# How do I stop Newman to run a collection on certain response code?

Tags: postman, newman, postman-newman

I'm relatively new to this,
How do I stop Newman to run a collection on certain response code? For example I want it to stop running on response 400 or 401 I tried the bail option but I guess I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for shedding some light.

Comment: Did you try `postman.setNextRequest(null)`?

Comment: Yes I did. It did not work